# Number sign issue when porting JavaScript code to Lua

Tags: javascript, lua, binary, bit-manipulation

I've been trying to port some JavaScript code to Lua. The code encodes and decodes data to and from a binary stream.

I am having an issue when trying to port some JavaScript code that can contain signed integers. The JavaScript code looks as such:

```js
function encodeVarint(val) {
    const bigval = BigInt(val);
    console.log('r1: ' + (bigval >> 63n).toString());
    console.log('r2: ' + (bigval << 1n).toString());
}

encodeVarint(-332222);
```

This code is based on code found in this library: https://github.com/hathora/bin-serde-ts/blob/develop/index.ts

I've added simplified versions of these functions here for testing: https://playcode.io/883024/

My Lua code is as such (with some logging to compare with PlayCode):

```
function encodeVarint(val)
    print("v", val)

    local r1 = bit.rshift(val, 63)
    local r2 = bit.lshift(val, 1)

    print("r1", r1)
    print("r2", r2)

    -- a work-around to get similar sign as in JavaScript
    local sign = val > 0 and 1 or -1

    local n = bit.bxor(r1, r2) * sign
    print("n", n)
    return tonumber(n)
end

function decodeVarint(val)
    local r1 = bit.rshift(val, 1)
    local r2 = -(bit.band(val, 1))
    return bit.bxor(r1, r2)
end
```

Based on code found here: https://github.com/wolf81/bit-serde-lua/blob/main/bit-serde/bit-serde.lua

The simplified example can be executed here: https://replit.com/@WolfgangSchreur/MysteriousEmbellishedSpools#main.lua

Now the problem that I'm seeing is that in the JavaScript code I get the following values for r1, r2:

```
r1: -1
r2: -664444
```

Whereas in the Lua code I get the following:

```
r1:  1
r2:  -664444
```

So I am guessing this makes the `bit.bxor()` method not do the thing it's supposed to. Since the sign is lost in the Lua version. Now as can be seen I manually add the sign, however this causes issues when the data byte length is too much (I guess an extra bit is added for the sign)

Any idea how to make the Lua code behave the same as the JavaScript code?

Comment: What are `val`, `readUVarint` and `writeUVarint`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @jabaa those values are all part of the libraries I've linked. They are not really important for my question I think. Just know that whatever I write with writeUVarint, I also can read with readUVarint.

The problem is before writing or reading, in the `r1` value that is `-1` in JavaScript for negative numbers and `1` in Lua.

Comment: Knowing the input argument is important for me to reproduce and debug the problem

Comment: I've used -332222 as input value.

You will see it will return the proper value with the above code (Lua same as JavaScript), but only due to the "sign hack" that I added in Lua

Comment: With your reputation, I would expect you to know how to provide all necessary details and a [mcve] in the question and that all questions on Stack Overflow have to be self-contained. You can add unnecessary, additional details in external links. Don't add important details in comments. If it's a bug in a library, you should ask the author to fix it. If it's a bug in your code, please provide all necessary variables and functions. If the functions and variables aren't important for your question, you should remove them from your question.

Comment: @jabaa I've simplified my examples

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: redeclaration of formal parameter val` for the JavaScript snippet. What is `r1` and `r2` in the JavaScript snippet?

Comment: It's written in TypeScript. As I am not a JavaScript dev myself, I am not 100% sure why this error shows up. The simplified example of encoding and decoding works fine in the playcode link though.

In the Lua code I extracted r1 & r2 for better debugging. In the JavaScript code r1 is `(bigval >> 63n)` and r2 is `(bigval << 1n)`

Comment: So the Lua code of (r1) `bit.rshift(val, 63)` is equivalent to the JavaScript code `(bigval >> 63n)` and the Lua code of (r2) `bit.lshift(val, 1)` is equivalent to the JavaScript code of `(bigval << 1n)`

Comment: Ah, I've modified the typescript code in playcode to be JavaScript code. It runs now.

Comment: `bit` library in Lua works with 32-bit numbers, not 64-bit.  What is the expected datatype of argument of function `encodeVarint`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff _"`bit` library in Lua works with 32-bit numbers, not 64-bit."_ What do you mean? According to http://bitop.luajit.org/ it supports 64-bit IEEE754 double and 64-bit integers.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff encodeVarint should be able to accept pretty much any number, however the `encodeUVarint()` function called by `encodeVarint()` in the actual project will limit numbers of bytes to 6 maximum for a number.

However, I believe I am in need of a big num library that doesn't rely on a C library and is able to do the xor operation. And that can work with signed integers. I have not been able to find a library with those requirements yet.

Comment: Did you read this [Right shift (>>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift)? _The right shift operator (`>>`) shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Copies of the leftmost bit are shifted in from the left. **Since the new leftmost bit has the same value as the previous leftmost bit, the sign bit (the leftmost bit) does not change. Hence the name "sign-propagating"**._

Comment: And [Lua Bit API Functions](http://bitop.luajit.org/api.html)? _Returns either the bitwise logical left-shift, bitwise logical right-shift, or bitwise arithmetic right-shift of its first argument by the number of bits given by the second argument.

**Logical shifts treat the first argument as an unsigned number and shift in 0-bits. Arithmetic right-shift treats the most-significant bit as a sign bit and replicates it.**
Only the lower 5 bits of the shift count are used (reduces to the range [0..31])._

Comment: JavaScript right shift operator keeps the sign bit. Lua `rshift` fills with `0` (positive sign bit). You could try `arshift`. This should have the same behavior for up to 31-bit shifts.

Comment: @jabaa thanks, arshift fixes the sign problem indeed. There's still another issue related to the large numbers, but I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @jabaa If you'd like to add a separate answer for the sign issue, I will upvote and accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's right shift operator keeps the sign bit:

> The right shift operator (`>>`) shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. **Copies of the leftmost bit are shifted in from the left. Since the new leftmost bit has the same value as the previous leftmost bit, the sign bit (the leftmost bit) does not change. Hence the name "sign-propagating".**

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift)

Lua's bit library has two functions for right shift:

1. `bit.rshift` fills with `0` (positivie sign bit) and
2. `bit.arshift` keeps the sign bit.

> Logical shifts treat the first argument as an unsigned number and shift in 0-bits. Arithmetic right-shift treats the most-significant bit as a sign bit and replicates it.

[Lua Bit API Functions](http://bitop.luajit.org/api.html)

`bit.arshift` has the same behavior for right shifts up to 31 bit.

Comment: Again I'd like to thank you very much. I fixed my other issue as well now (reading part) by converting the unsigned number to a 64 bit number. So now the code properly handles signed numbers up to 6 bytes for both encoding and decoding.